# jquery function val() is not equivalent to "$(this).value="?

Tags: jquery

When I try to set a text input to blank (when clicked) using `$(this).value=""`, this does not work. I have to use `$(this).val('')`.

Why? What is the difference? What is the mechanism behind the `val` function in jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user_name').focus(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
// error code: not working...
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user_name').focus(function(){
        $(this).value='';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You want:

```
this.value = ''; // straight JS, no jQuery
```

or

```
$(this).val(''); // jQuery
```

With `$(this).value = ''` you're assigning an empty string as the `value` property of the jQuery object that wraps `this` -- not the `value` of `this` itself.

Answer (score 17):

`$(this).value` is attempting to call the 'value' property of a jQuery object, which does not exist. Native JavaScript *does* have a 'value' property on certain HTML objects, but if you are operating on a jQuery object you must access the value by calling `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that :

`typeof $(this)` is **JQuery** object.

and

`typeof $(this)[0]` is **HTMLElement** object

then :
if you want to apply `.val()` on HTMLElement , you can add this extension .

```
HTMLElement.prototype.val=function(v){
   if(typeof v!=='undefined'){this.value=v;return this;}
   else{return this.value}
}
```

Then :

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').val() ==== $('#myDiv').val()
```

And

```
 document.getElementById('myDiv').val('newVal') ==== $('#myDiv').val('newVal')
```

## `العكس` INVERSE :

Converselyو if you want to add value property to jQuery object , follow those steps :

1. Download the full source code (not minified) i.e: example http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js .
2. Insert Line after L96 , add this code `value:""` to init this new prop
   [image]
3. Search on `jQuery.fn.init` , it will be almost Line 2747

[image]

4. Now , assign a value to `value` prop : (Before return statment add `this.value=jQuery(selector).val()`)
   [image]

## Enjoy now :  $('#myDiv').value

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is this:

```
$(this)[0].value = "Something";
```

This allows jQuery to return the javascript object for that element, and you can bypass jQuery Functions.

Comment: It is silly, but it's not `this` that you should be using, but the original CSS selector.