# value undefined for jquery

Tags: jquery

here is my jquery

```
 var obj=$("#Connect");
  alert($("#Connect").value);
```

The value appeared to be undefined, but I have a html tag there

```
<input type="button" id="Connect" value="Connect"/>
```

what is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4524715/622813

Answer (score 3):

you are mixing jquery and javascript here...correct way to get value in jquery is `val()`

try this

**jquery**

```
alert($("#Connect").val());
```

**javascript**

```
 alert(document.getElementById("Connect").value);
```

Comment: thanks, is there a list of whole set of attributes? say I wish to get tagName, I also failed to get it using .tagName

Comment: @william007 http://api.jquery.com As a rule you don't access any attributes directly. The jQuery object is not the same thing as the DOM element it refers to.

Comment: @Juhana, wow, the list is long to memorize

Comment: That's why the list is there so you don't have to :)

Comment: hahaha :).. @Juhana.. that was funny.. :)