# Validate all input fields inside a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am using below jQuery function to validate all fields inside a div. My problem is it always return false even I fill all the fields.

```
function validate(id) {
            //:text, :checkbox, select, textarea
            var isFormValid = true;
            var div = $(id);
            $(div).find(":text, select").each(function () {
                if (this.value == "" && !$(this).hasClass("no-req")) {
                    $(this).addClass("required");
                    isFormValid = false;
                    $(this).focus();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).removeClass("required");
                }
            });
            if (!isFormValid) {
                alert("Please fill all the higlighted fields!");
            }
            return isFormValid;

        }
```

On Asp.net button client click I am using this code

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" class="btn btn-success" OnClientClick="javascript: return validate('#tdAdd');"   OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Comment: did you tried `OnClientClick="validate('#tdAdd');"`

Comment: The function seems to work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/s5rfhsa9/1/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$(div).find(":text, select").each(function () {
    if (this.val() == "" && !$(this).hasClass("no-req")) {
```

To:

```
div.find(":text, select").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "" && !$(this).hasClass("no-req")) {
```

Comment: question tagged as jQuery, that is not jQuery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524702/jquery-function-val-is-not-equivalent-to-this-value

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a build-in aspnet Custom Validator? You can then search all TextBoxes inside a specific `div` and return the Validator value.

```
<div id="validateTheseControls">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    ClientValidationFunction="validateControlsInDiv" ErrorMessage="Not all fields are filled"></asp:CustomValidator>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateControlsInDiv(sender, element) {
        var isValid = true;

        $('#validateTheseControls input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });

        element.IsValid = isValid;
    }
</script>
```