# .val Function Javascript Equivalent isnt functioning?

Tags: javascript

(If something isnt wrote right, please edit, Im not SUPER good with english language)
So i need save the Input’s Value in javascript, and Ive tried use .value with a selector, but it fails to return the value.

[jquery function val() is not equivalent to "$(this).value="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524702/jquery-function-val-is-not-equivalent-to-this-value)
This question had some valuable insight, but didnt answer my question.

```js
var Value = document.getElementById("test").value;

function save() { 
 localStorage.setItem("note"}, Value);
}

(function() {
 Value = localStorage.getItem("note"));
})();
```

Basically I tried to save my data from an input, Im using inputs in settings page of another project, and I need settings to reload once my page is reloaded.

```html
<input id=“test” placeholder=“Write Here”>
<button onclick=“save()”>Execute</button>
```

So I really expected it to reload the value of my settings input, and have the data I saved there when I reloaded my page, but nothing happened. I want it to save my data and reload it on page entering.

Comment: You need to get the value after the user clicks.

Comment: Disable “smart quotes” in your editor. It’s `""`, not `“”`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors; try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser — when does `Value` change?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh sorry I was typing this from phone, pc blocked stackoveflow, cant post in pc, sorry. I fixed now.

Comment: is that closing bracket actually there iun the second line of save, or is that a typo from a phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a lot of mistakes....
Here is the solution...

**HTML**

```
<input id="test" placeholder="Write Here">
<button onclick="save()">Execute</button>
```

**JS**

```
var Item  = document.getElementById("test");

function save() { 
 localStorage.setItem("note", Item.value);
}

(function() {
 Item.value = localStorage.getItem("note");
})();
```

Comment: Thankyou, This seemed to do the trick, I guess I using the value property incorrect. Thanks again.